# Creating a custom wordpress plugin with shortcode

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to create my first Wordpress plugin that includes a shortcode and I can't seem to get it to work.  When I type my shortcode [first] it just displays "[first]" even though it's written in HTML in the post/page.  What am I missing?

```
 <?php
 /*
 * Plugin Name: WordPress ShortCode
* Description: Create your WordPress shortcode.
* Version:
* Author:
 * Author URI:
*/

 function wp_first_shortcode(){
  echo "Hello World";
 }

add_shortcode(‘first’, ‘wp_first_shortcode’);
 ?>
```

There are no errors, just shortcode is not displaying properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` don't `echo`. From [the add_shortcode() docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode):

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce
>   output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is
>   to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly
>   will lead to unexpected results. This is similar to the way filter
>   functions should behave, in that they should not produce expected side
>   effects from the call, since you cannot control when and where they
>   are called from.

So:

```
function wp_first_shortcode(){
  return "Hello World";
}
```

Also don't use curly quotes in your code. Ever. Change `add_shortcode(‘first’, ‘wp_first_shortcode’);` to `add_shortcode('first', 'wp_first_shortcode');`

See also https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/basic-shortcodes/

Comment: Thanks, it was the curly quotes.  I had copied and pasted from a tutorial and wasn't even thinking about the quotation marks.  Replaced them and it works.